# Perl (wrong?) encoding of output file

Tags: perl, utf-8, character-encoding, latin1

I am running Active Perl 5.16.3 on Windows 7 (32 bits).

My (short) program massages an input text file (encoded in UTF-8). I wish the output encoding to be in Latin1, so my code is:

```
open (OUT, '>;encoding(Latin1)', "out.txt") || die "Cannot open output file: $!\n";
print OUT "$string\n";
```

yet the resulting file is still in UTF-8. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you really have a semicolon in the open mode string? It should be a colon - `>:encoding(Latin1)`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the encoding layer is separated from the open mode by a colon, not a semicolon.

```
open OUT, '>:encoding(latin1)', "out.txt" or die "Cannot open output file: $!\n";
```

Secondly, Latin-1 can only encode a small subset of UTF-8. Furthermore, most of this subset is encoded the same in both encodings. We therefore have to use a test file with characters that are not encoded the same,  e.g. `\N{MULTIPLICATION SIGN}` U+00D7 `×`, which is `\xD7` in Latin-1, and  `\xC3\x97` in UTF-8.

Make also sure that you actually decode the input file.

Here is how you could generate the test file:

```
$ perl -CSA -E'say "\N{U+00D7}"' > input.txt
```

Here is how you can test that you are properly recoding the file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $in, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", "input.txt";
open my $out, ">:encoding(latin1)", "output.txt";

while (<$in>) {
    print { $out } $_;
}
```

The `input.txt` and `output.txt` should afterwards have different lengths (3 bytes → 2 bytes).